# Annotation class does not validate input as enum in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, annotations

I'd like to create annotation instead of enum use it for **when** statement

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@IntDef(SELECT.toLong(), WEAR.toLong(), BAND.toLong())
annotation class CurrentState

companion object {
    const val SELECT = 0
    const val WEAR = 1
    const val BAND = 2
} 

private fun handleFragment(@CurrentState state:Int) {
    val fragment:Fragment =
    when(state){
        SELECT -> SelectDeviceFragment.newInstance()
        WEAR -> ConnectWatchFragment.newInstance()
        BAND -> SelectDeviceFragment.newInstance()
    }
```

From my understanding, this code should prevent me from performing following code:

```
handleFragment(5)
```

and when statement should not ask me to add **else** statement, as expected from enum
What I'm doing wrong or misunderstand?

Answer (score 1):

From https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/intdef-and-stringdef-not-being-checked-at-compile-time/7029:

> This checking doesn’t come from the compiler, but from Android lint. Work to make android lint language independent is being done, but if I’m not mistaken you’ll need a newer version of Android Studio for it.

And [Android Studio 3.1 blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/android-studio-3-1.html) mentions lint checks for Kotlin as a feature (though it doesn't say whether this check specifically is supported).

Answer (score 1):

The `@IntDef` annotation is part of the Android framework. The compiler is not aware of any specific semantics of this annotation, and is not able to use it for checking the exhaustiveness of `when` statements.

Moreover, even with the annotation, you can call `handleFragment(5)`. Such code will not be a compiler error, it will only be reported as a lint warning.